# Discord Bot to sync "Booster" role between two servers doesn't work properly

Tags: discord.js

I tried seeking for answers at the documentation of Discord.js but wasn't able to find anything useful.
I also tried several means and asked around (some JS devs). They didn't have a clue what the problem is.
The bot is supposed to do what was stated above. It was written in JS using discord.js.

Here's the code:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    ],
});

const mainServerId = "998283287481036820";
const subServerId = "1058071888775090256";
const boosterRoleName = "Booster";

client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Eingeloggt als ${client.user.tag}`);
});

client.on("guildMemberUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
  syncBoosterRole(oldMember, newMember);
});

async function syncBoosterRole(oldMember, newMember) {
  const mainServer = client.guilds.cache.get(mainServerId);
  const subServer = client.guilds.cache.get(subServerId);

  const boosterRoleMain = mainServer.roles.cache.find(
    (role) => role.name === boosterRoleName,
  );
  const boosterRoleSub = subServer.roles.cache.find(
    (role) => role.name === boosterRoleName,
  );

  if (!boosterRoleMain || !boosterRoleSub) {
    console.error("Rolle nicht gefunden.");
    return;
  }

  const isBoosterOnMain = oldMember.roles.cache.has(boosterRoleMain.id);
  const isBoosterOnSub = newMember.roles.cache.has(boosterRoleSub.id);

  if (isBoosterOnMain && !isBoosterOnSub) {
    // Wenn auf dem Mainserver die Booster-Rolle hinzugefügt wurde, füge sie dem Subserver hinzu
    await newMember.roles.add(boosterRoleSub);
    console.log(
      `Booster-Rolle zu ${newMember.user.tag} auf dem Subserver hinzugefügt.`,
    );
  } else if (!isBoosterOnMain && isBoosterOnSub) {
    // Wenn auf dem Mainserver die Booster-Rolle entfernt wurde, entferne sie auch auf dem Subserver
    await newMember.roles.remove(boosterRoleSub);
    console.log(
      `Booster-Rolle von ${newMember.user.tag} auf dem Subserver entfernt.`,
    );
  }
}

client.login("Gib mir den Token");
```

Comment: Have you enabled the "Server Members Intent" in the bot's Discord Developer Portal? It would also help if you could clarify how you would expect your code to work and what exactly is currently not working as you expect it.

Comment: Well: 
The bot is supposed to sync the "Booster" role between a main and a sub server. 
There aren't any error codes. It just doesn't work.
The setting itself is enabled.

Comment: Yeah but you can add some helpful knowledge to those trying to help you such as:
- Does it correctly recognize when the user has the role on the sub server but not on the main server and vice-versa?
- If it does, does it not remove or add the role as it is supposed to?

The more details you add the easier it is for people to help you out

Comment: See, when we tried it following happened:
The role was neither added nor was it working as intended. 
That means concretly: 
Apparently, the bot actually finds the role (since if it doesn't find the role, it would send an error message in the channel). But it doesn't add the role. The bot has the permissions temporarily set to "Admin" so that can't be the issue. 
Our test scenario:
One adds the role "Booster" on the main server and it should assign that role on the backup server. And that's the problem: It doesn't assign the role on the second server, aka Backup server.